# T-SQL Pass constant value into procedure/function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I recently noticed DateDiff isn't very accurate, so wanted to write a more accurate version

Example of datediff not being accurate

```
DECLARE @sTime as DATETIME ='12/31/2013 23:59:59'
DECLARE @eTime as DATETIME ='01/01/2014 00:00:00'
SELECT 
    DateDiffYears   = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @sTime, @eTime)
,   DateDiffMonths  = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @sTime, @eTime)
,   DateDiffDays    = DATEDIFF(DAY, @sTime, @eTime)
,   DateDiffHours   = DATEDIFF(HOUR, @sTime, @eTime)
,   DateDiffMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @sTime, @eTime)
,   DateDiffSeconds = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @sTime, @eTime)
-- expected results: 0 year, 0 month, 0 day, 0 hour, 0 minute, 1 second
-- actual results:   1 year, 1 month, 1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, 1 second
```

My question is, can you pass in a constant value like DAY, SECOND, HOUR, etc into a custom function.

Example:

`SELECT dbo._newDateDiff(YEAR, @sTime, @eTime)`

I assume the only way to do this is to pass in a string value of 'YEAR', 'MONTH', etc. Is this true?

Thanks,

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981089/sql-server-passing-unquoted-constants-to-functions-like-datepart-does

Comment: @christiandev Why no vote to close as dupe? Fundamentally the same question. With the same answer. No it isn't possible.

Comment: I wouldn't describe what `datediff()` does as "not accurate".  It is very well documented and does *exactly* what it is supposed to do (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).  You simply need another function.

Comment: is it really that hard to do `'dd'`?

Comment: Totally easy to do 'dd', this problem just led me to wonder if you could pass sql constant values like day, time, wd, etc into a function. If it were possible it would limit the invalid string exceptions that can occur at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, for example you could make a procedure out of this (a function won't allow EXECUTE within):

```
declare @datepart char(2)
declare @stime char(19)
declare @etime char(19)
declare @sql varchar(100)
set @datepart = 'ss'
set @stime = '12/31/2013 23:59:59'
set @etime = '01/01/2014 00:00:00'
set @sql = 'SELECT DATEDIFF('+@datepart+','''+@stime+''','''+@etime+''')'
exec (@sql)
```

...with which you can define which datepart you want to compare and the stime and etime.

```
CREATE PROC _newDateDiff (@datepart CHAR(2),@stime CHAR(19),@etime CHAR(19))
AS
BEGIN
declare @sql varchar(100)
set @sql = 'SELECT DATEDIFF('+@datepart+','''+@stime+''','''+@etime+''')'
exec (@sql)
END

EXEC _newDateDiff 'SS','12/31/2013 23:59:59','01/01/2014 00:00:00'
```

Or you can put the values into a table with the datetime datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE DATET
(
DID INT,
DT DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO DATET VALUES (1,'12/31/2013 23:59:59')
INSERT INTO DATET VALUES (1,'01/01/2014 00:00:00')

SELECT DISTINCT DID,MAX(DT)-MIN(DT) FROM DATET GROUP BY DID
```